# Unable to extract themes pack to /usr/share/themes

Tags: themes

When I try to extract theme packs to `/usr/share/themes/` it shows `you don't have right permission to extract archives in the folder /themes/`.

What should I do?

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Try using sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the permission settings of `/usr/share/themes/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  151 root root  4096 Nov  7 06:50 themes
```

As you can see it is owned by the user `root` and group `root`. Moreover it has no `write` permissions for even the `group` members let alone `others`.

So the solution is to run `sudo <command_to_extract_theme>` or become `root` by `sudo su` and then `<command_to_extract_theme>`, the first option is preferable always.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know what you are are doing, and even when you do, I suggest you to just extract the themes and put it on your ~/.themes directory in your home. Create it if doesn't exist.

Also for icons theme use the ~/.icons directory

You can select and switch themes in unity with unity tweak tool.